# Why does `new` have a higher precedence than member access in this case?

Tags: javascript

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Why is this interpreted as `(new Date()).getTime()` and not `new (Date().getTime())`? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), member access has a higher precedence than `new`.

Comment: It's the same precendence (18)

Comment: And `new ... (...)` is a circumfix, so the direction rules don't apply. Thus, `new foo.bar(baz)` clearly instantiates a new `foo.bar`; `new foo(baz).bar` clearly instantiates a new `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member access has the same precedence as new (18) and evaluated from L to R, new is evaluated first.